# Forcing ld to resolve weak references at ld time

Tags: c, linux, linker, binutils

Consider a program like:

```
#include <stdio.h>
void foo() __attribute__((__weak__));
int main()
{
    printf("%p\n", (void *)foo);
    if (foo) foo();
}
```

If compiled as a regular, non-PIE dynamic-linked executable, the non-existence of `foo` is resolved at `ld` time, and even if `LD_PRELOAD` is used to define `foo`, it will not be seen. On the other hand, if the program is compiled as PIE, weak dynamic symbol references end up in the output, and `LD_PRELOAD` can make the symbol `foo` visible.

Is there a way to force the non-PIE behavior (resolving the nonexistence of the weak-referenced symbol at ld time, rather than at runtime) for PIE executables?

Answer (score 0):

A function with this attribute has its name emitted as a weak
symbol instead of a global name. This is primarily for the naming
of library routines that can be overridden by user code.

weak symbol
Having two or more global symbols of the same name will not cause a conflict as long as all but one of them are declared as being weak symbols. The linker ignores the definitions of the weak symbols and uses the normal global symbol definition to resolve all references, but the weak symbols will be used if the normal global symbol is not available. A weak symbol can be used to name functions and data that can be overridden by user code. A weak symbol is also referred to as a weak alias, or simply weak.

From internet!